# What part of manga is this on Dragonball? (NSFW)

Tags: dragon-ball-series

What part of manga is this on Dragonball? I've just seen this and the image seems legit to me.

> [image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

It's from [Dragon Ball H](http://thedragonballblog.blogspot.com/2013/02/dragon-ball-h-volume-2-goku-x-chichi.html) (link may be little NSFW, it's mostly censored). It's a doujin drawn by a circle called "Garland".